# Update state with API Call - React.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, state

I'm trying to update state in React.js using an API call, as I need to show some of the data to the end user.
The api call works through localhost:5001 and is stored in Firebased functions.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Table.css';


class Table extends Component {
  constructor (props)
  {
     super(props);
      this.state = {
         stocks: []
     };
 }

   componentDidMount() {
    fetch('localhost:5001') // Removed for stackoverflow //
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(stockList => {
        this.setState =
        ({ stocks: stockList });
    });
}

   render() {
      return (
         <div className='table'>
            <h1 id='title'>Companies</h1>
            {this.state.stocks.map(stocks => <h2 key={stocks.symbol}> {stocks.companyName}</h2>)}
         </div>
      )
   }
 }

export default Table;
```

Here is a snippet of the API call:

```
{"symbol":"AAPL","companyName":"Apple Inc"}
```

Comment: It should be `this.setState({ stocks: stockList });`, rather than `this.setState = ({ stocks: stockList });` in order to update the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState is a function, so you should call it, rather that assign values to it:

```
this.setState({ stocks: stockList });
```